# Using .sort(function (a, b) to list parsed xml data in descending numerical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

So basically i have this xml feed that lists housing properties into a custom wordpress theme [the xml feed is hosted on expertagent] and ive been trying to get the results to output in descending numerical order which is dictated by the price value within each xml "item" [in this case "property"]. Ive got the feed to display the properties by their status [for sale, sold etc] but i cant seem to get this part to work. I either break the feed or the code i put in does nothing at all!

Note: im not usually the one to deal with the javescript or jquery side of things so im pretty novice with this.

here is my .js file and my current attempt:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "properties2.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {

    $(xml).find("property").each(function() {

        var priority = $(this).find("priority").text();
        if(priority.startsWith('On Market')) {
            $("#xmlmain").append("<div class='xmlwrapper'><div class='xmlleft'><img src='"+$(this).find('[name="Photo 1"]').text()+"'/></div><div class='xmlright'><h2>"+$(this).find("advert_heading").text()+"</h2><p class='price'>"+$(this).find
            ("price_text").text()+"</p><p class='priority'>"+$(this).find("priority").text()+"</p><p>"+$(this).find("main_advert").text()+"</p><a href='"+$(this).find("web_link").text()+"' target='_blank'>VIEW > </a></div></div>");
        }
        else {
            if(priority.startsWith('Under Offer')) {
                $("#xmlmain").append("<div class='xmlwrapper'><div class='xmlleft'><img src='"+$(this).find('[name="Photo 1"]').text()+"'/></div><div class='xmlright'><h2>"+$(this).find("advert_heading").text()+"</h2><p class='price'>"+$(this).find
                ("price_text").text()+"</p><p class='priority'>"+$(this).find("priority").text()+"</p><p>"+$(this).find("main_advert").text()+"</p><a href='"+$(this).find("web_link").text()+"' target='_blank'>VIEW > </a></div></div>");
            }     
        }    

    });

    $('#xmlmain').find('numeric_price').text().sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).attr('numeric_price') - $(b).attr('numeric_price');
    })
    .appendTo('#xmlmain');

}
});
```

Obviously the bit below was the part i was using to try and sort it but clearly ive either made some rookie error or im not on the right track as it literally does nothing!

```
$('#xmlmain').find('numeric_price').text().sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).attr('numeric_price') - $(b).attr('numeric_price');
})
.appendTo('#xmlmain');
```

So im trying to get the properties to list from highest price to lowest [but it would be nice to know how to swap that around] within their priority.startsWith section. The price data is contained in the "price_text" and/or the "numeric_price" element. With the code i have, ive tried both, But im assuming numeric_price is the better one to use as it doesnt contain anything except numerical data.

Here is also an example of the xml feed:

```
<properties>
<property reference="MR139">
    <instructedDate>06/08/2018 17:07:05</instructedDate>
    <price_text>£600,000</price_text>
    <numeric_price>600000.0000</numeric_price>
    <priority>On Market</priority>
    <advert_heading>house for sale</advert_heading>
    <main_advert>some text about the property</main_advert>
    <web_link>www.example.com</web_link>
    <property_style>Detached</property_style>
    <property_reference>111111</property_reference>
    <newHome>NO</newHome>
    <noChain>NO</noChain>
    <furnished>Unknown</furnished>
    <currency>GBP</currency>
    <featuredProperty>NO</featuredProperty>
    <pictures>
      <picture name="Photo 1" lastchanged="2018-08-06T15:44:48.5800534Z">
          <filename>example.jpg</filename>
      </picture>
    </pictures>
</property>
</properties>
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Calling `text()` on multiple elements returns a single string (all text content concatenated), and jQuery has no `sort()` function.

Comment: ok that would explain why it doesnt do anything. What can i use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sort function you need:

```js
function priceSort(a, b) {
  return Number($(b).find('numeric_price').text()) - Number($(a).find('numeric_price').text());
}
```

Just like when creating your HTML, you need to `find()` the price, then grab its `text()`, since it's a child node, not an attribute. You also need to convert it to a Number, or JavaScript will compare them as strings.

You can use the function in your existing code, replacing the first line of `parseXml()` like this:

```js
$($(xml).find("property").get().sort(priceSort)).each(function() {
```

This first grabs all properties, calls `get()` to convert them to an array of non-jQuery nodes, calls `sort()` on the array, then passes the result back to `$()` to convert it into a jQuery collection again. Finally, `each()` is called to create the HTML parts.

Comment: Awesome, this almost works for me, it does order the properties how i wish but it seems to be now not displaying my else loop, so its only displaying the if(priority.startsWith('On Market')) in order. --- here is the code https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/VEeQJZ?editors=0010#0

Comment: @Moose I removed the else part from my example to keep it short (and because I couldn't find the difference between the two blocks)

Comment: thats fine, i was just wondering what i did wrong incorporating what you showed me that excludes the else section

Comment: No wait, ignore me lol. it hasnt excluded it, i was jsut being blind!